# Go back from current activity to previous activity

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I have two activities. If I'm in activity 2, and want to go back to activity 1, how can I create a button to go back to the previous activity?

Comment: it depends on what you want to use for going back to previous activity .... using mobile hardware key or ..using a button in activity 2...tell me??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using device back key.

Or programmatically you can add one button in your activity 2 and on button click finish current activity.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            finish();
        }
    });
```